# Sumifs - sum of column ignoring N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with an error code 1004. I am attempting to have a SUMIF formula in my VBA code. My objective is to Sum Column F from F2 to the lastrow. the column has Vlookup values that include "#N/A". The formula used without VBA is

`=SUMIF(F2:F3509, "> 0")`

My attempted formula in VBA is

```
lastRow = Range ("A1048576").End(xlup).Row
Range("D" & lastrow) = "=SUMIF(F2:F, ""> 0""" & lastrow & ")"
```

. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much. Matt

Comment: Are you after `Range("D" & lastrow) = "=SUMIF(F2:F" & lastrow & ", "">0"")"`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is exactly what I was looking for. I updated my code a little. I now have added in `lastrow2 = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row`, for my other insert. `lastrow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`  My final end code reads. `Range("F" & lastrow) = "=SUMIF(F2:F" & lastrow2 & ", "">0"")"`

Comment: You could adopt Ahmed's approach of just adding 1 to your variable, and maybe use Rows.count rather than hardcoding 1048576 even if unlikely to make much difference in practical terms

Comment: Thanks ill switch over. To the cleaner version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Lastrow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("D" & Lastrow) = "=SUMIF(F2:F" & Lastrow & "," & Chr(34) & "> 0" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all the rows your last row must be from F column. If your column A has different number of elementos than F, that will not work.

You can also use SUMPRODUCT

```
lastrow = Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Row
mRange = "F2:F" & lastrow
Range("D" & lastrow) = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & mRange & " >  0 ), " & mRange & " ) "
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the AGGREGATE function:

```
Type=9 'Choose type of aggregation (9=sum)
Option=6 'Choose an option (6=Ignore error values including NA)
MySum=Application.Worksheetfunction.Aggregate(Type,Option,MyRange)
```

Comment: Not only does this not help in putting a formula in a cell, it is using a wrong formula to begin with.